# Why is my dataveiw filter crashing

Tags: filter, dataview

i have a dataview from a data table i am trying to filter to see if there are duplicate values for a manufacture, Type and Serial number but i am getting an error

string strFilter = "Manufacture = " + strMake + " and Type = " + strModel + " and Serial Number = " + strSn;

strfilter = "Manufacture = ford 150 and Type = Raptor and Serial Number = 9999"

dv.RowFilter = strFilter;

this it the error i am getting

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SyntaxErrorException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error: Missing operand after 'Number' operator

Comment: Do you need single quotes for strings?

Comment: That helped but still having issue it does not like the fact the "Serial Number" is two words if i change it to Serial_Number it is ok.

Comment: Write serial number in brackets like [Serial number] if that is the name of your column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need single quotes for strings.Write serial number in brackets like [Serial number] if that is the name of your column.

Comment: Serial number looks int. You may not need single quotes there.

Answer (score 0):

For one you are missing a semi colon here.

strfilter = "Manufacture = ford 150 and Type = Raptor and Serial Number = 9999" <---------

:)

Comment: Ok i have it working up to the Serial Number for some reason it does not like the fact the column name is two words.strfilter = "Manufacturer = 'ford 150' and Type = 'Raptor' and Serial Number = '9999'"